# Failed to connect to Internet using Huawei E1550 mobile broadband in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mobile-broadband, huawei

I have been trying to use my mobile broadband usb for hours but without succeed.

It works on another windows device I have, also I managed to send a SMS message using `modem-manager-gui` to another device, but It failed to connect to the internet, also I've put the right APN in the network.

Sometimes it connects to the network but I tried to open google without succeed, and the modem disconnects after that.

I addition, when I first plug the modem and click on connect it did not show the `the Set up a Mobile Broadband Connection wizard` mentioned in [Connect to mobile broadband](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-mobile.html.en)

I appreciate any help.

Here is some outputs that may help:

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b721 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 12d1:140c Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E180v
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

mmcli -m 17

```
  -----------------------------
  General  |              path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/17
           |         device id: 71750f780fd09df30082649ad163fecaf726bd11
  -----------------------------
  Hardware |      manufacturer: HUAWEI COMMUNICATION
           |             model: 33
           | firmware revision: M6246A-KPRBL-1.2.0014_8H  1  [Feb 25 2010 15:51:57]
           |      h/w revision: 401200E1
           |         supported: gsm-umts
           |           current: gsm-umts
           |      equipment id: 353443044992266
  -----------------------------
  System   |            device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
           |           drivers: qmi_wwan, option
           |            plugin: huawei
           |      primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |             ports: cdc-wdm0 (qmi), ttyUSB0 (at), ttyUSB1 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (at), 
           |                    wwan0 (net)
  -----------------------------
  Status   |              lock: sim-pin2
           |    unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-puk (10), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk2 (10)
           |             state: registered
           |       power state: on
           |       access tech: umts
           |    signal quality: 78% (recent)
  -----------------------------
  Modes    |         supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                    allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                    allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none
           |           current: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
  -----------------------------
  IP       |         supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  -----------------------------
  3GPP     |              imei: 353443044992266
           |     enabled locks: fixed-dialing
           |       operator id: 41701
           |     operator name: SYRIATEL
           |      registration: home
  -----------------------------
  SIM      |  primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/17
```

usb-devices:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=11
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.15.0-33-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 31 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=140c Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI Technology
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  64 Ivl=2ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qmi_wwan
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  64 Ivl=2ms
E:  Ad=84(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
E:  Ad=85(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=04(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
E:  Ad=86(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=05(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=87(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=06(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=88(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.15.0-33-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms
```